# Error with Contact Custom Field in Advanced Search

Tags: custom-fields, search

We had an issue with the addresses of our contacts, so for now we added a temporal custom field that saves the province of that contact, so we can easily filter them. The thing is that when I do an advanced search filtering for that field, it doesn't show any results. What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the custom field you created isn't searchable.

You can fix this by editing the custom field and ticking the box that says 'Is this field searchable?'

[image]